# Javascript from bootstrap theme not working - Symfony Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony, npm, bootstrap-5, webpack-encore

I'm using a bought Bootstrap theme and Symfony with Webpack Encore.

The given JS of the theme seems not to be working.

In my app.js file, which is the entrance in webpack config, I import the JS file of the theme, called theme.js.
In this theme.js file are imported the others js files that are those I'm trying to use.

Here is my theme.js file

```
import passwordVisibilityToggle from './components/password-visibility-toggle';
import inputFormatter from './components/input-formatter';
import formValidation from './components/form-validation';
import stickyNavbar from './components/sticky-navbar';
import smoothScroll from './components/smooth-scroll';
import scrollTopButton from './components/scroll-top-button';
import tooltip from './components/tooltip';
import popover from './components/popover';
import toast from './components/toast';
import rangeSlider from './components/range-slider';
import dropdownSelect from './components/dropdown-select';
import carousel from './components/carousel';
import gallery from './components/gallery';
import lightbox from './components/lightbox';
import datePicker from './components/date-picker';
import subscriptionForm from './components/subscription-form';
import interactiveMap from './components/interactive-map';
import parallax from './components/parallax';
import fileUploader from './components/file-uploader';
import bindedInputValue from './components/binded-input-value';
import masterCheckbox from './components/master-checkbox';
import toggleClass from './components/toggle-class';
```

The components file is in the same folder as my app.js.

In the base.html.twig file I refer the app.js file created via Webpack

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

When I check the console in Chrome, I see this error for example :
app.a14306e2.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined

which comes from this :

```
;noUiSlider.create(a,{start:i,connect:l,step:o.dataStep,tooltips:!0,range:{min:o.dataMin,max:o.dataMax},...
```

Here is the package.json file :

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "cleave.js": "^1.6.0",
        "filepond": "^4.28.2",
        "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.4",
        "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.6",
        "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "^2.0.6",
        "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.7",
        "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "^2.0.10",
        "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "^3.8.6",
        "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
        "jarallax": "^1.12.7",
        "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
        "lg-fullscreen.js": "^1.2.0",
        "lg-thumbnail.js": "^1.2.0",
        "lg-video.js": "^1.3.0",
        "lg-zoom.js": "^1.3.0",
        "lightgallery.js": "^1.4.0",
        "nouislider": "^15.5.0",
        "parallax-js": "^3.1.0",
        "prismjs": "^1.24.1",
        "simplebar": "^5.3.5",
        "smooth-scroll": "^16.1.3",
        "tiny-slider": "^2.9.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^2.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.0.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.27.4",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "del": "^6.0.0",
        "emitty": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-pug": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
        "gulp-rollup": "^2.17.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "sass": "^1.36.0",
        "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
        "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress",
        "build-gulp": "gulp"
    }
}
```

I have ran already 'npm install','npm build', 'npm dev'
I think there is something I don't understand in the way how webpack encore works.

I need some help :/

Comment: Do you have webpack.config.js configured? https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes with a standard Bootstrap installation, if you try to use the bootstrap.js functions from a script in your Twig template it is not loaded yet, and it throws a similar error. This can be overcome by putting your script directly into your app.js file, otherwise you have to check that the components are loaded first. The example below is from my Symfony 4.4 project with webpack Bootstrap 5, this demonstrates what is necessary to initialize a Modal from the twig template ( I later moved just the contents of the function `run` to app.js).
This will check that `bootstrap` is defined before proceeding (I'm using jQuery but the logic will be the same regardless):

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      let turns = 0
      const turnKey = function () {
        turns++
        // console.log(turns + ' attempt to start...')
        if (typeof bootstrap !== typeof undefined) {
          console.log('running...')
          return run()
        }
        if (turns > 100){
          // give up, something is wrong, not starting
          return false
        }
        setTimeout(turnKey, 10)
      }
      const run = function () {
        // Bootstrap is loaded
        window.spinner = new bootstrap.Modal($('#loadingSpinner'), {
          'backdrop': 'static',
          'keyboard': false
        })
        console.log('...ran')
      }
      turnKey()
  })
</script>
```

Note this always worked for me on the first call to `turnKey()`